# About the use of \DeclareFixedFont and available fonts

Tags: fonts, pdftex

I'm working with latex and I want to change font locally. There are plenty of ways of doing that, but the one I'm interested in is using the included font (in `fontenc`), without having to download a font package. I know it's achievable, because I can use 
`\DeclareFixedFont {⟨cmd⟩} {⟨encoding⟩} {⟨**family**⟩} {⟨series⟩} {⟨shape⟩} {⟨size⟩}` 
and then use ⟨cmd⟩ to change font locally.
The ⟨family⟩ parameter is defined (as I understood it) as a series of letters coding for a font type, for example `cmtt`, or `cmr` (Computer Modern Roman). I want it to work with pdfLaTeX (I know there is stuff that works only with LuaTeX and XeTex, but that's not what I'm looking for)

I did nor find in any documentation, nor the latex font catalogue, nor the latex font guide, nor ..., a way to know all available family, or they corresponding letter code. There's always a few examples with a note saying there's too many to be listed.

So here's my question : where one could find such a list ?

Comment: There is no complete list as everyone can add a new one if they want. If you know a package that loads the font you can look into it to find out the font family name the package uses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\DeclareFixedFont {⟨cmd⟩} {⟨encoding⟩}{family}...
```

will work if there is a file named  `<encoding><family>.fd` in tex's input path

```
 grep '[.]fd' $(kpsewhich --all ls-R)
```

would list all such files in the standard places.

In an up to date texlive 2023 there are almost 5 thousand such files:

```
$ grep '[.]fd' $(kpsewhich --all ls-R) | wc -l
4754
```

This will include a few special purpose fd files not intended for pdflatex, and does not include files in directories not included in the pre-cached `ls-R` file listings, but is  a fairly  accurate list in practice.

You can get a more managable list by looking for a specific encoding, eg T1 has 794:

```
grep -i -h '^t1.*[.]fd' $(kpsewhich --all ls-R)  | sort | uniq
T1AccanthisADFStdNoThree-LF.fd
T1Alegreya-Inf.fd
T1Alegreya-LF.fd
T1Alegreya-OsF.fd
T1Alegreya-Sup.fd
T1Alegreya-TLF.fd
T1Alegreya-TOsF.fd
T1AlegreyaSans-Inf.fd
T1AlegreyaSans-LF.fd
T1AlegreyaSans-OsF.fd
T1AlegreyaSans-Sup.fd
T1AlegreyaSans-TLF.fd
T1AlegreyaSans-TOsF.fd
T1AlgolRevived-Inf.fd
T1AlgolRevived-OsF-TT.fd
T1AlgolRevived-OsF.fd
T1AlgolRevived-Sup.fd
T1AlgolRevived-TLF-TT.fd
T1AlgolRevived-TLF.fd
T1Almndr-OsF.fd
T1AlphaSlabOne-Sup.fd
T1AlphaSlabOne-TLF.fd
T1AmiciLogo.fd
T1ArchivZero-LF.fd
T1ArchivZero-OsF.fd
T1ArchivZero-Sup.fd
T1ArchivZero-TLF.fd
T1ArchivZero-TOsF.fd
T1Arimo-TLF.fd
T1Arvo-TLF.fd
T1AuriocusKalligraphicus.fd
T1Baskervaldx-LF.fd
T1Baskervaldx-OsF.fd
T1Baskervaldx-Sup.fd
T1Baskervaldx-TLF.fd
T1Baskervaldx-TOsF.fd
T1BaskervilleF-Dnom.fd
T1BaskervilleF-LF.fd
T1BaskervilleF-OsF.fd
T1BaskervilleF-Sup.fd
T1BaskervilleF-TLF.fd
T1BaskervilleF-TOsF.fd
T1Bttr-TLF.fd
T1Cabin-Sup.fd
T1Cabin-TLF.fd
T1Caladea-TLF.fd
T1CascadiaCodThree-Sup.fd
T1CascadiaCodThree-TLF.fd
T1Chivo-Dnom.fd
T1Chivo-Inf.fd
T1Chivo-LF.fd
T1Chivo-Numr.fd
T1Chivo-OsF.fd
T1Chivo-Sup.fd
T1Chivo-TLF.fd
T1Chivo-TOsF.fd
T1Cinzel-LF.fd
T1CinzelDecorative-LF.fd
T1Clara-Sup.fd
T1Clara-TLF.fd
T1Clara-TOsF.fd
T1ClearSans-TLF.fd
T1Cochineal-Dnom.fd
T1Cochineal-Inf.fd
T1Cochineal-LF.fd
T1Cochineal-OsF.fd
T1Cochineal-Sup.fd
T1Cochineal-TLF.fd
T1Cochineal-TOsF.fd
T1Coelacanth-LF.fd
T1Coelacanth-OsF.fd
T1Coelacanth-TLF.fd
T1Coelacanth-TOsF.fd
T1ComicNeue-TLF.fd
T1ComicNeueAngular-TLF.fd
T1CormorantGaramond-Inf.fd
T1CormorantGaramond-LF.fd
T1CormorantGaramond-OsF.fd
T1CormorantGaramond-Sup.fd
T1CormorantGaramond-TLF.fd
T1CormorantGaramond-TOsF.fd
T1CourierOneZeroPitch-TLF.fd
T1CpHwt-Sup.fd
T1CpHwt-TLF.fd
T1Crimson-TLF.fd
T1CrimsonPro-Inf.fd
T1CrimsonPro-LF.fd
T1CrimsonPro-OsF.fd
T1CrimsonPro-Sup.fd
T1CrimsonPro-TLF.fd
T1CrimsonPro-TOsF.fd
T1Crlt-Inf.fd
T1Crlt-LF.fd
T1Crlt-OsF.fd
T1Crlt-Sup.fd
T1Crlt-TLF.fd
T1Crlt-TOsF.fd
T1DANTE.fd
T1DejaVuSans-TLF.fd
T1DejaVuSansCondensed-TLF.fd
T1DejaVuSansMono-TLF.fd
T1DejaVuSerif-TLF.fd
T1DejaVuSerifCondensed-TLF.fd
T1Domitian-Inf.fd
T1Domitian-Sup.fd
T1Domitian-TLF.fd
T1Domitian-TOsF.fd
T1EBGaramond-Inf.fd
T1EBGaramond-LF.fd
T1EBGaramond-OsF.fd
T1EBGaramond-Sup.fd
T1EBGaramond-TLF.fd
T1EBGaramond-TOsF.fd
T1EBGaramondInitials-TLF.fd
T1ETbb-Dnom.fd
T1ETbb-Inf.fd
T1ETbb-LF.fd
T1ETbb-OsF.fd
T1ETbb-Sup.fd
T1ETbb-TLF.fd
T1ETbb-TOsF.fd
T1FiraMono-Sup.fd
T1FiraMono-TLF.fd
T1FiraMono-TOsF.fd
T1FiraSans-LF.fd
T1FiraSans-OsF.fd
T1FiraSans-Sup.fd
T1FiraSans-TLF.fd
T1FiraSans-TOsF.fd
T1Frm-LF.fd
T1GaramondLibre-Inf.fd
T1GaramondLibre-LF.fd
T1GaramondLibre-OsF.fd
T1GaramondLibre-Sup.fd
T1Gelasio-LF.fd
T1Gelasio-OsF.fd
T1Gelasio-Sup.fd
T1Gelasio-TLF.fd
T1Gelasio-TOsF.fd
T1GilliusADF-LF.fd
T1GilliusADFCond-LF.fd
T1GilliusADFNoTwo-LF.fd
T1GilliusADFNoTwoCond-LF.fd
T1Go-TLF.fd
T1GoMono-TLF.fd
T1Gudea-TLF.fd
T1Heuristica-Inf.fd
T1Heuristica-Sup.fd
T1Heuristica-TLF.fd
T1Heuristica-TOsF.fd
T1HindMadurai-TLF.fd
T1IBMPlexMono-Sup.fd
T1IBMPlexMono-TLF.fd
T1IBMPlexSans-Sup.fd
T1IBMPlexSans-TLF.fd
T1IBMPlexSerif-Sup.fd
T1IBMPlexSerif-TLF.fd
T1IMFELLEnglish-TLF.fd
T1IbarraRealNova-LF.fd
T1IbarraRealNova-OsF.fd
T1IbarraRealNova-Sup.fd
T1InriaSans-LF.fd
T1InriaSans-OsF.fd
T1InriaSans-Sup.fd
T1InriaSans-TLF.fd
T1InriaSans-TOsF.fd
T1InriaSerif-LF.fd
T1InriaSerif-OsF.fd
T1InriaSerif-Sup.fd
T1InriaSerif-TLF.fd
T1InriaSerif-TOsF.fd
T1Inter-LF.fd
T1Inter-Sup.fd
T1Inter-TLF.fd
T1JanaSkrivana.fd
T1JosefinSans-LF.fd
T1Junicode-Inf.fd
T1Junicode-Sup.fd
T1Junicode-TLF.fd
T1Junicode-TOsF.fd
T1Lbstr-LF.fd
T1LibertinusMono-TLF.fd
T1LibertinusSans-LF.fd
T1LibertinusSans-OsF.fd
T1LibertinusSans-Sup.fd
T1LibertinusSans-TLF.fd
T1LibertinusSans-TOsF.fd
T1LibertinusSerif-LF.fd
T1LibertinusSerif-OsF.fd
T1LibertinusSerif-Sup.fd
T1LibertinusSerif-TLF.fd
T1LibertinusSerif-TOsF.fd
T1LibertinusSerifDisplay-LF.fd
T1LibertinusSerifDisplay-OsF.fd
T1LibertinusSerifDisplay-Sup.fd
T1LibertinusSerifDisplay-TLF.fd
T1LibertinusSerifDisplay-TOsF.fd
T1LibertinusSerifInitials-TLF.fd
T1LibreBodoni-Inf.fd
T1LibreBodoni-Sup.fd
T1LibreBodoni-TLF.fd
T1LibreBskvl-LF.fd
T1LibreBskvl-Sup.fd
T1LibreCsln-Inf.fd
T1LibreCsln-LF.fd
T1LibreCsln-OsF.fd
T1LibreCsln-Sup.fd
T1LibreCsln-TLF.fd
T1LibreCsln-TOsF.fd
T1LibreFranklin-Sup.fd
T1LibreFranklin-TLF.fd
T1LinguisticsPro-LF.fd
T1LinguisticsPro-OsF.fd
T1LinuxBiolinumO-LF.fd
T1LinuxBiolinumO-OsF.fd
T1LinuxBiolinumO-TLF.fd
T1LinuxBiolinumO-TOsF.fd
T1LinuxBiolinumT-LF.fd
T1LinuxBiolinumT-OsF.fd
T1LinuxBiolinumT-Sup.fd
T1LinuxBiolinumT-TLF.fd
T1LinuxBiolinumT-TOsF.fd
T1LinuxLibertineDisplayT-LF.fd
T1LinuxLibertineDisplayT-OsF.fd
T1LinuxLibertineDisplayT-Sup.fd
T1LinuxLibertineDisplayT-TLF.fd
T1LinuxLibertineDisplayT-TOsF.fd
T1LinuxLibertineInitialsT-LF.fd
T1LinuxLibertineInitialsT-OsF.fd
T1LinuxLibertineInitialsT-TLF.fd
T1LinuxLibertineMonoT-LF.fd
T1LinuxLibertineMonoT-Sup.fd
T1LinuxLibertineMonoT-TLF.fd
T1LinuxLibertineO-LF.fd
T1LinuxLibertineO-OsF.fd
T1LinuxLibertineO-TLF.fd
T1LinuxLibertineO-TOsF.fd
T1LinuxLibertineT-LF.fd
T1LinuxLibertineT-OsF.fd
T1LinuxLibertineT-Sup.fd
T1LinuxLibertineT-TLF.fd
T1LinuxLibertineT-TOsF.fd
T1LukasSvatba.fd
T1Magra-TLF.fd
T1Merriwthr-LF.fd
T1Merriwthr-OsF.fd
T1Merriwthr-Sup.fd
T1Merriwthr-TLF.fd
T1Merriwthr-TOsF.fd
T1MerriwthrSans-LF.fd
T1MerriwthrSans-OsF.fd
T1MerriwthrSans-Sup.fd
T1MerriwthrSans-TLF.fd
T1MerriwthrSans-TOsF.fd
T1MintSpirit-Inf.fd
T1MintSpirit-LF.fd
T1MintSpirit-OsF.fd
T1MintSpirit-Sup.fd
T1MintSpirit-TLF.fd
T1MintSpirit-TOsF.fd
T1MintSpiritNoTwo-Inf.fd
T1MintSpiritNoTwo-LF.fd
T1MintSpiritNoTwo-OsF.fd
T1MintSpiritNoTwo-Sup.fd
T1MintSpiritNoTwo-TLF.fd
T1MintSpiritNoTwo-TOsF.fd
T1Montserrat-Dnom.fd
T1Montserrat-Inf.fd
T1Montserrat-LF.fd
T1Montserrat-Numr.fd
T1Montserrat-OsF.fd
T1Montserrat-Sup.fd
T1Montserrat-TLF.fd
T1Montserrat-TOsF.fd
T1MontserratAlternates-Dnom.fd
T1MontserratAlternates-Inf.fd
T1MontserratAlternates-LF.fd
T1MontserratAlternates-Numr.fd
T1MontserratAlternates-OsF.fd
T1MontserratAlternates-Sup.fd
T1MontserratAlternates-TLF.fd
T1MontserratAlternates-TOsF.fd
T1Mrcls-LF.fd
T1Mrcls-Sup.fd
T1NimbusMono.fd
T1NimbusMonoN.fd
T1NimbusSans.fd
T1NimbusSerif.fd
T1NotoSans-LF.fd
T1NotoSans-OsF.fd
T1NotoSans-Sup.fd
T1NotoSans-TLF.fd
T1NotoSans-TOsF.fd
T1NotoSansMono-Sup.fd
T1NotoSansMono-TLF.fd
T1NotoSansMono-TOsF.fd
T1NotoSerif-LF.fd
T1NotoSerif-OsF.fd
T1NotoSerif-Sup.fd
T1NotoSerif-TLF.fd
T1NotoSerif-TOsF.fd
T1Nunito-Sup.fd
T1Nunito-TLF.fd
T1Nunito-TOsF.fd
T1OldStandard-Sup.fd
T1OldStandard-TLF.fd
T1Ovrlck-LF.fd
T1Ovrlck-OsF.fd
T1PTMono-TLF.fd
T1PTSans-TLF.fd
T1PTSansCaption-TLF.fd
T1PTSansNarrow-TLF.fd
T1PTSerif-TLF.fd
T1PTSerifCaption-TLF.fd
T1PlyfrDisplay-LF.fd
T1PlyfrDisplay-OsF.fd
T1PlyfrDisplay-Sup.fd
T1PoiretOne-LF.fd
T1Quattro-LF.fd
T1Quattro-Sup.fd
T1QuattroSans-LF.fd
T1QuattroSans-Sup.fd
T1Raleway-TLF.fd
T1Raleway-TOsF.fd
T1Roboto-LF.fd
T1Roboto-OsF.fd
T1Roboto-TLF.fd
T1Roboto-TOsF.fd
T1RobotoMono-TLF.fd
T1RobotoSerif-LF.fd
T1RobotoSerif-OsF.fd
T1RobotoSerif-Sup.fd
T1RobotoSerif-TLF.fd
T1RobotoSerif-TOsF.fd
T1RobotoSlab-TLF.fd
T1Rosario-Dnom.fd
T1Rosario-Inf.fd
T1Rosario-LF.fd
T1Rosario-Numr.fd
T1Rosario-OsF.fd
T1Rosario-Sup.fd
T1Rosario-TLF.fd
T1Rosario-TOsF.fd
T1STEP-Inf.fd
T1STEP-Sup.fd
T1STEP-TLF.fd
T1STEP-TOsF.fd
T1SourceCodePro-Dnom.fd
T1SourceCodePro-Numr.fd
T1SourceCodePro-Sup.fd
T1SourceCodePro-TLF.fd
T1SourceCodePro-TOsF.fd
T1SourceSansPro-Dnom.fd
T1SourceSansPro-Inf.fd
T1SourceSansPro-LF.fd
T1SourceSansPro-Numr.fd
T1SourceSansPro-OsF.fd
T1SourceSansPro-Sup.fd
T1SourceSansPro-TLF.fd
T1SourceSansPro-TOsF.fd
T1SourceSerifPro-Dnom.fd
T1SourceSerifPro-LF.fd
T1SourceSerifPro-Numr.fd
T1SourceSerifPro-OsF.fd
T1SourceSerifPro-Sup.fd
T1SourceSerifPro-TLF.fd
T1SourceSerifPro-TOsF.fd
T1Spectral-LF.fd
T1Spectral-OsF.fd
T1Spectral-Sup.fd
T1Spectral-TLF.fd
T1Spectral-TOsF.fd
T1SticksTooText-Dnom.fd
T1SticksTooText-Inf.fd
T1SticksTooText-LF.fd
T1SticksTooText-Numr.fd
T1SticksTooText-OsF.fd
T1SticksTooText-Sup.fd
T1SticksTooText-TLF.fd
T1SticksTooText-TOsF.fd
T1TeXGyreScholaX-Inf.fd
T1TeXGyreScholaX-LF.fd
T1TeXGyreScholaX-OsF.fd
T1TeXGyreScholaX-Sup.fd
T1TeXGyreScholaX-TLF.fd
T1TeXGyreScholaX-TOsF.fd
T1Tempora-Sup.fd
T1Tempora-TLF.fd
T1Tempora-TOsF.fd
T1TheanoDidot-TLF.fd
T1TheanoDidot-TOsF.fd
T1TheanoModern-TLF.fd
T1TheanoModern-TOsF.fd
T1TheanoOldStyle-TLF.fd
T1TheanoOldStyle-TOsF.fd
T1Tinos-TLF.fd
T1UniversalisADFStd-LF.fd
T1XCharter-Dnom.fd
T1XCharter-Inf.fd
T1XCharter-LF.fd
T1XCharter-Numr.fd
T1XCharter-OsF.fd
T1XCharter-Sup.fd
T1XCharter-TLF.fd
T1XCharter-TOsF.fd
T1XCharterTH-osf.fd
T1XCharterTH-tlf.fd
T1Zeroswald-Sup.fd
T1Zeroswald-TLF.fd
T1andk-TLF.fd
T1atkinsn-LF.fd
T1atkinsn-Sup.fd
T1atkinsn-TLF.fd
T1cantarell-LF.fd
T1cantarell-OsF.fd
T1cantarell-TLF.fd
T1cantarell-TOsF.fd
T1charssil-TLF.fd
T1cmodh.fd
T1cmor.fd
T1cmoss.fd
T1cmott.fd
T1cmovt.fd
T1comfortaa.fd
T1dad.fd
T1droidsans.fd
T1droidsansmono.fd
T1droidserif.fd
T1erewhon-Dnom.fd
T1erewhon-Inf.fd
T1erewhon-LF.fd
T1erewhon-Numr.fd
T1erewhon-OsF.fd
T1erewhon-Sup.fd
T1erewhon-TLF.fd
T1erewhon-TOsF.fd
T1fbb-Inf.fd
T1fbb-LF.fd
T1fbb-OsF.fd
T1fbb-Sup.fd
T1fbb-TLF.fd
T1fbb-TOsF.fd
T1ffm.fd
T1ffmw.fd
T1lato-LF.fd
T1lato-OsF.fd
T1lato-TLF.fd
T1lato-TOsF.fd
T1opensans-LF.fd
T1opensans-OsF.fd
T1opensans-TLF.fd
T1opensans-TOsF.fd
t1aer.fd
t1aess.fd
t1aett.fd
t1anonymouspro.fd
t1antp.fd
t1antpl.fd
t1antt.fd
t1anttc.fd
t1anttl.fd
t1anttlc.fd
t1aram.fd
t1artemisia.fd
t1artemisiaeuler.fd
t1augie.fd
t1auncl.fd
t1bch.fd
t1beuron.fd
t1bodoni.fd
t1ccr.fd
t1clm.fd
t1clm2.fd
t1clm2d.fd
t1clm2dj.fd
t1clm2j.fd
t1clm2jqs.fd
t1clm2js.fd
t1clm2jt.fd
t1clm2jv.fd
t1clm2qs.fd
t1clm2s.fd
t1clm2t.fd
t1clm2v.fd
t1clmd.fd
t1clmdj.fd
t1clmj.fd
t1clmjqs.fd
t1clmjs.fd
t1clmjt.fd
t1clmjv.fd
t1clmqs.fd
t1clms.fd
t1clmt.fd
t1clmv.fd
t1cmbr.fd
t1cmdh.fd
t1cmfib.fd
t1cmfr.fd
t1cmg.fd
t1cmin.fd
t1cmr-1200.fd
t1cmr.fd
t1cmsd.fd
t1cmsrbr.fd
t1cmsrbs.fd
t1cmsrbt.fd
t1cmss.fd
t1cmtl.fd
t1cmtt.fd
t1cmvtt.fd
t1copsn.fd
t1cpc.fd
t1cpr.fd
t1cugar.fd
t1cyklop.fd
t1cypr.fd
t1egoth.fd
t1etr.fd
t1fav.fd
t1fcm.fd
t1fcs.fd
t1fct.fd
t1fmm.fd
t1fnc.fd
t1foekfont.fd
t1fonetika.fd
t1frc.fd
t1fut-sup.fd
t1fut.fd
t1futj.fd
t1futs.fd
t1futx.fd
t1fve.fd
t1fvm.fd
t1fvs.fd
t1fxl1.fd
t1gentium.fd
t1gentiumbook.fd
t1givbc.fd
t1gvibc.fd
t1hfodh.fd
t1hfor.fd
t1hfoss.fd
t1hfott.fd
t1hfovt.fd
t1hmin.fd
t1huncl.fd
t1imaj.fd
t1imin.fd
t1ipxg.fd
t1ipxm.fd
t1iwona.fd
t1iwonac.fd
t1iwonal.fd
t1iwonalc.fd
t1jkp.fd
t1jkpf.fd
t1jkpfosn.fd
t1jkpk.fd
t1jkpkf.fd
t1jkpkfosn.fd
t1jkpkos.fd
t1jkpkosn.fd
t1jkpkvos.fd
t1jkpl.fd
t1jkplf.fd
t1jkplfosn.fd
t1jkplk.fd
t1jkplkf.fd
t1jkplkfosn.fd
t1jkplkos.fd
t1jkplkosn.fd
t1jkplkvos.fd
t1jkplos.fd
t1jkplosn.fd
t1jkplvos.fd
t1jkpos.fd
t1jkposn.fd
t1jkpss.fd
t1jkpssf.fd
t1jkpssfosn.fd
t1jkpssk.fd
t1jkpsskf.fd
t1jkpsskfosn.fd
t1jkpsskos.fd
t1jkpsskosn.fd
t1jkpsskvos.fd
t1jkpssos.fd
t1jkpssosn.fd
t1jkpssvos.fd
t1jkptt.fd
t1jkpttos.fd
t1jkpttosn.fd
t1jkpttvos.fd
t1jkpvos.fd
t1jkpx.fd
t1jkpxf.fd
t1jkpxfosn.fd
t1jkpxk.fd
t1jkpxkf.fd
t1jkpxkfosn.fd
t1jkpxkos.fd
t1jkpxkosn.fd
t1jkpxkvos.fd
t1jkpxos.fd
t1jkpxosn.fd
t1jkpxvos.fd
t1jtm.fd
t1kurier.fd
t1kurierc.fd
t1kurierl.fd
t1kurierlc.fd
t1laess.fd
t1laett.fd
t1lcmss.fd
t1lcmtt.fd
t1linb.fd
t1llcmss.fd
t1llcmtt.fd
t1lmdh.fd
t1lmr.fd
t1lmros.fd
t1lmss.fd
t1lmssos.fd
t1lmssq.fd
t1lmtt.fd
t1lmttos.fd
t1lmvtt.fd
t1lmvttos.fd
t1mak.fd
t1maksf.fd
t1mdbch.fd
t1mdici.fd
t1mdpgd.fd
t1mdpus.fd
t1mdput.fd
t1mdputu.fd
t1mdugm.fd
t1mincochineal.fd
t1minebgaramond.fd
t1minlibertine.fd
t1minntx.fd
t1minxcharter.fd
t1mlmdh.fd
t1mlmr.fd
t1mlmss.fd
t1mlmssq.fd
t1mlmtt.fd
t1mlmvtt.fd
t1nab.fd
t1nanumgt.fd
t1nanummj.fd
t1neohellenic.fd
t1newtxtt.fd
t1newtxttz.fd
t1npxtt.fd
t1ntxdnom.fd
t1ntxinf.fd
t1ntxlf.fd
t1ntxosf.fd
t1ntxsups.fd
t1ntxth-lf.fd
t1ntxth-osf.fd
t1ntxth-tlf.fd
t1ntxth-tosf.fd
t1ntxtlf.fd
t1ntxtosf.fd
t1ntxtt.fd
t1oands.fd
t1pag.fd
t1pbk.fd
t1pbsi.fd
t1pcr.fd
t1pcrs.fd
t1pgoth.fd
t1phnc.fd
t1phv.fd
t1pmhg.fd
t1pnc.fd
t1ppl.fd
t1pplj.fd
t1pplx.fd
t1proto.fd
t1ptm.fd
t1put.fd
t1pxr.fd
t1pxss.fd
t1pxtt.fd
t1pzc.fd
t1qag.fd
t1qbk.fd
t1qcr.fd
t1qcs.fd
t1qhv.fd
t1qhvc.fd
t1qpl.fd
t1qtm.fd
t1qzc.fd
t1rtnd.fd
t1rust.fd
t1rzcm.fd
t1rzcm.fdd
t1sarab.fd
t1sqrc.fd
t1srbtiks.fd
t1stix.fd
t1stix2.fd
t1tgoth.fd
t1tib.fd
t1trjn.fd
t1txr.fd
t1txss.fd
t1txtt.fd
t1uag.fd
t1uaq.fd
t1ubk.fd
t1ucr.fd
t1udidot.fd
t1ugq.fd
t1uhv.fd
t1unc.fd
t1uncl.fd
t1uni.fd
t1upl.fd
t1uplmr.fd
t1utm.fd
t1uzc.fd
t1vik.fd
t1vlmr.fd
t1vlmss.fd
t1vlmssq.fd
t1vlmtt.fd
t1vlmvtt.fd
t1wedn.fd
t1wela.fd
t1wesa.fd
t1wesu.fd
t1weva.fd
t1xcmss.fd
t1ybd.fd
t1ybd0.fd
t1ybd1.fd
t1ybd2.fd
t1ybd2j.fd
t1ybdj.fd
t1ybv.fd
t1ybvw.fd
t1yes.fd
t1yes0.fd
t1yes1.fd
t1yesj.fd
t1yesjw.fd
t1yesw.fd
t1yfrak.fd
t1yly.fd
t1ylyw.fd
t1yrd.fd
t1yrda.fd
t1yrdaw.fd
t1yrdw.fd
t1yv1.fd
t1yv1d.fd
t1yv2.fd
t1yv3.fd
t1yvo.fd
t1yvoa.fd
t1yvoad.fd
t1yvod.fd
t1yvt.fd
t1yvtajw.fd
t1yvtaw.fd
t1yvtd.fd
t1yvtj.fd
t1yvtjw.fd
t1yvtw.fd
t1zcsth-lf.fd
t1zcsth-osf.fd
t1zi4.fd
t1zlmtt.fd
t1zlmvtt.fd
t1zpldnom.fd
t1zplinf.fd
t1zpllf.fd
t1zplnumr.fd
t1zplosf.fd
t1zplsubs.fd
t1zplsups.fd
t1zplth-lf.fd
t1zplth-osf.fd
t1zplth-tlf.fd
t1zplth-tosf.fd
t1zpltlf.fd
t1zpltosf.fd
```

Comment: Thanks, this is a very helpful answer, but then :

1) How do get only the available **families** ? (`cmtt` exists with 48 encodings for me)

 and 2) How do you link the letters with the font name ? i.e. how am I suppose to know that `cmtt` stands for Computer Modern Typewriter ?

Comment: @Theragondin the available families in T1 encoding are the list above if you delete `t1` or `T1` from the start and `.fd` from the end.  as for the rest you just need to read the documentation, `cmtt` for example doesn't really stand for "Computer Modern Typewriter" the font name is `cmtt`. The fact that it's the monspace font in the Computer Modern collection is documented in several places, not least the texbook

Comment: Yes, I guessed the name construction, and it would be fine if there were just T1 encoding, but there are plenty of those, all the OT*, the C*, OM*, with various numbers and letters. My goal is to visualize them, google doesn't know `cmtt` but do know Computer Modern Typewriter. I understand the nuance that `cmtt` doesn't _stand_ for "the monospace font in the Computer Modern collection", but I'm precisely looking for the bijection between those abbreviations and the full name of the font, or that description, in a unique document, for all listed families.

Comment: @Theragondin you can start by looking up in the texlive catalog  which tl package installed that file, then look what doc is in the same package. But you are looking at the work of hundreds of people over several decades, documentation will be variable

Comment: @Theragondin you could buy the third edition of the LaTeX companion. There is a long chapter about fonts with lots of details. see chapter 10 in the samples https://www.latex-project.org/help/books/tlc3-digital-chapter-samples.pdf